# Google+ login crashes

Tags: ios, authentication, crash, google-plus

App crashes on G+ login.

Crashlytics report it occurs in method:

```
[GPPSignIn addSavedKeychainName:]
```

Exception is:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
[___NSArrayM insertObject:AtIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

My code is:

```
- (void)googleLogin
{
    GPPSignIn *gppSignIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    gppSignIn.clientID = GOOGLE_CLIENTID;
    gppSignIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, nil];
    gppSignIn.delegate = self;
    gppSignIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    gppSignIn.attemptSSO = YES;

    [SVProgressHUD show];
    [gppSignIn authenticate];
}
```

Did anyone else had this problem and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by your call to

```
[gppSignIn authenticate];
```

Instead, try:

```
[gppSignIn trySilentAuthentication];
```

If you want the user to automatically be signed in.

You might also want to try passing your scopes as string constants to make sure something isn't happeneing with the `kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin` value:

```
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 @"login",
                 nil];
```

Also of note, it's possible that signing the user out when this state is reached could resolve issues:

```
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
```

Comment: I was getting s sporadic an NSInvalidArgumentException on trySilentAuthentication and the signout solved it for me. I had checked the expirationDate before I tried the signIn. Upvoted

Comment: NSInvocation fetcherWithRequest: more details on my error which you helped fix, for future reference